# Using Arch Linux as Noob Need Help: Wifi Randomly Dropping

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dns, arch-linux

Alright so I am using PAL3.0 aka Purdue Airlink and have random connection drops very frequently where it will go to 0 B/s Up and 0 B/s Down and persist for a while and sometimes will it resolve itself. Also to note, when I am using my home network I NEVER have this problem it is only a thing when I am at campus and using the unis network.

I used journalctl -f to check out whats going on.
I am seeing 3 reoccurring msgs when my wifi drops.

First I see this message but I have observed that it normally prints this before the next two I will mention every time connection drops:
Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server

Then I normally see one of these two alternate: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server || Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server

What I have done so far:
Set DNSSEC=no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and restarted and the msgs and connection problem still prevail.

Let me know anything yall need to help me troubleshoot or any solutions you guys know of. Thx.

Comment: it is only a thing when I am at campus and using the unis network.   ..... Have you asked University IT?  Do other students nave an issue with this network?

Comment: that's the annoying thing, i called them and they said "since it deals w linux we don't have anyone qualified to help you"

Comment: I don't know how we can help. Linux systems I have (Ubuntu and Kali) connect to wired and wireless networks just fine. But I do not know anything about your network specifications there.

Comment: yeah i might just migrate to ubuntu at this point and i dont think i will have problems there until im sufficient in debugging this stuff on my own for arch